# How can I write unittest in this specific scenario? Or is it a bad unittest?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have two date variables like below:

```
$startDate = new \DateTime('2013-01-01');
$endDate = new \DateTime()->format(\DateTime::ISO8601);
```

If I count the difference between two dates, on every test run the result will be different. So, I can't use any constant number to assert the difference is correct but my test should make sure that at any given time the difference between those two dates are perfect!

How can I achieve that? Any comments or suggestions would be really beneficial! Cheers!

Comment: I've not tried this,but is it not possible to mock the DateTime class `format` method so that it gives you a predictable value?

Answer (score 3):

For permit that your test don't depend from a system clock or some other you can do something like this: Suppose to have a simple function that calculate the age in year, you can add a second argument at your function that that the current date, if not set, the default is now:

// DateRangeUtil

```
public static function getYearAge($registrationDate,$now = null)
{
    if (!$now)
    {
        $now = new \DateTime('now');
    }

    return $now->diff($registrationDate)->format("%y");
}
```

// DateRangeUtilTest

```
public function testGetYearAge()
{
    $bornDate  = \Datetime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i:s", "01/03/2014 00:00:00");
    $today = \Datetime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i:s", "01/06/2015 00:00:00");
    $this->assertEquals(1, DateRangeUtil::getYearAge($bornDate, $today)," expect one year old");
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: How this line is valid: "$this->assertEquals(1,DateRangeUtil::getYearAge(\Datetime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i:s", "01/03/2014 00:00:00"),\Datetime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i:s", "01/06/2015 00:00:00")));"

Comment: Hi @SMAlMamun i update my answer for better readability, the specific test case you mention is that if I have 1year and 3 mount, i want to return only the year part, so the function will return 1. Hope this clarify the answer and help you

Comment: You are writing code to satisfy a unit test. Not ideal.

Comment: Hi @Drumbeg thanks for your comment, sometime i need to adapt my code to be testable. how you solve this situation in a scenario like this? What you could suggest to solve the answer posted?

Comment: of course, but you must pass the mocked object at the function?

Comment: I was thinking by maybe redeclaring the DateTime class in the test. Old School, but I've seen it done. I'm not sure if its possible though, so perhaps your approach is the way to go.

Comment: thanks @Drumbeg for sharing, i will explore your suggestion. Do you have some resource/reference/example on this approach? thanks in advice

Comment: I'm struggling to find a link to a good example. It's just a case of redeclaring the DateTime class at the top of the test file and writing the functions of the class how you see fit. I know a lot of developers who used to mock in this way before mocking libraries were around. However, I'm not sure if DateTime is actually mockable?

Comment: Dont worry i undestand what you mean

Comment: @Drumbeg It should be possible, we mocked DateTimeUtil in a test to figure the problem that I asked here!

Comment: hi @SMAlMamun so you solved your problem? can you share your solution?

Comment: @Matteo we re-factored lots of things, it might not be possible to post the complete solution here! We mocked DateTimeUtil and I can post that part if you want :)

Comment: @Drumbeg People write unittest to support their codebase but if you need to add some more stuffs in your codebase to make a unittest more solid and working one, that's much better! According to my knowledge, you should be able to cut your code into pieces and all of those pieces should be supported by unittest!

Comment: Another thing, I went through this link and learnt a lot: https://jtreminio.com/2013/03/unit-testing-tutorial-part-5-mock-methods-and-overriding-constructors/

Comment: @SMAlMamun It shouldn't really be a case of adding some stuff to a codebase to make a test more solid. This is wrong. However, I think I was wrong as well is suggesting that you shouldn't change your code at all; a piece of code that is difficult to test indicates a potential design problem.